# Can't access Prometheus through Browser though Ports are open

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, prometheus, monitoring, grafana

I try to monitor EC2-Instances(AWS) with Prometheus and Grafana. So I have one Instance installed with Prometheus (lets call it Monitoring-Instance), Grafana and the Node-Exporter to monitor itself and another Instance (Target Instance) where I installed just the Node-Exporter to get the metrics of this Instance. Everything good so far and I'm able to access the metrics of both Instances(through Port 9100) and I can also reach Grafana (Port 3000). But I'm not able to reach the Prometheus Board on my Monitoring-Instance. And also I can't ping my Monitoring-Instance through my Target-instance or the other way. Ports open for Internet-Ingress on Monitoring (3000,9090,9100,22) Ports open for Internet-Ingress on Target-Instance (9100,22).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself, I simply messed up my prometheus.yml so Prometheues didn't start <.<.
But I would be interested in the question why I can't ping one instance from another though they exist in the same vpc and subnet oO

Comment: security groups are implicit deny, explicit permit.  Unless you have a rule permitting ICMP to the host, ICMP will not be permitted.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, i thought the security groups would just regulate the internet part. I will try this =)